# Java threads and POSIX threads, User or kernel level?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, operating-system, semaphore

Pretty new to threads and OS constructs here,

was wondering if anyone could clear something up for me.

When implementing threads in C you have access to POSIX threads, is a POSIX thread an OS level thread? Running at the kernel level?

And in Java when creating and running threads, are these user level threads? What level of access do we have to OS level constructs in java? Are semaphores in Java just set in the user space?

Thanks in advance for any insight into any of these questions.

Comment: What are ' OS level constructs'?  Obviously, I/O will require OS support, as will semaphores and the like sychro mechanisms that can require threads to wait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX threads are kernel threads. Kernel threads are "normal" threads; you'd know if you were using user threads in C (because you'd have to write the whole threading system yourself).

Java threads are also kernel threads, usually. On Unix-like systems, they may use POSIX threads; on Windows, they use Windows threads. It is conceivable that there is a JVM for a system without threads, and it implements threads itself (as user threads).

Comment: Thanks @immibis that cleared quite a bit up for me. As far as semaphores go, when implementing semaphores in C vs Java. Would it be safe to say that C gives a bit lower level access to semaphores? Say process level vs. thread level? Or is this available in Java as well?

Comment: @pipedreams2 What is a "process level semaphore" or "thread level semaphore"?

Comment: sorry if I may be getting some terminology wrong I am fairly new in this area. As far as my understanding goes a semaphore is a tool for synchronization, In C you have access to these at an kernel or operating system level and can access these by different processes even if they reside outside of the current programs address space. In Java all reference to semaphores I have seen is through threads. So wondering if Java supports interprocess communication through semaphores? How do Semaphores in Java differ from in C?

Comment: @pipedreams2 - they don't, because alll such synchro requirements are delegated to the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ***@user253751*** answer's, another indication that, TYPICALLY, threads created using the pthread libaray are (essentially) kernel threads, is due to the value passed in the second parameter to `pthread_create`. A common (but not mandatory) usage of this API will be in  a way that the `attr` argument will be NULL --> which means that this thread will be a kernel (aware) thread.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
                   const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
                   void *(*start_routine)(void *),
                   void *restrict arg);
```